# How to get the Input checkbox id value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input checkbox something like this..

```
 <input class="inputchbox" id="Pchk" type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%=Model.ID%>" />
```

using javascript I need to get the all checkbox checked Ids in to the array?

how  do I need to get?

thanks

Comment: Where are the other checkboxes? What control are you using to group the checkboxes? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I am suing jquery but I am not getting the all the checkbox ids.. in IE8.. but i am getting in Firefox..

Comment: same input checkbox generates with differnt id's..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pure Javascript answer**

```
var formelements = document.forms["your form name"].elements;
var checkedElements = new Array();
for (var i = 0, element; element = formelements[i]; i++) {
  if (element.type == "checkbox" && element.checked) [
    checkedElements.push(element);
  }
}
```

**Jquery Answer**

```
$("input:checked")
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this look like a solution to your issue? [Parse page for checkboxes via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183419/parse-page-for-checkboxes-via-javascript)

Basically, you'd get the element for your `<input type="checkbox">` tag and verify whether or not the `checked` attribute evaluates to true.

*Note: I'm unsure if my response should be a comment or an answer -- this almost looks like a duplicate question?*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
var checks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {  
    checks .push(inputs[i]);  
  }  
}
```

using jQuery you could do this:

```
var checks= $("input:checkbox:checked");
```

Comment: This si not working in IE8?
var checks= $("input[@type=checkbox]:checked");

Comment: `@type`? I think the `@` was left behind in jQuery 1.2.6. :o)

Comment: I used the code which Durilai sujjested in Friefox I am getting all values but in IE I am getting only Frist Id value other id value are zero its showing

Comment: @patrick - good catch, old code. Updated to use jQuerys latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
  var checkboxes = new Array();

    var $checkboxCtrls  = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    $.each($checkboxCtrls,function(i,ctrl){

        checkboxes.push($(this).attr('id'));

    });
```

Fiddle link for Assistance : http://jsfiddle.net/gJeCT/1/

- Note: for IE, comment the console logging statement and use alert(), as console logging is supported in all browsers except IE versions.